# @Singleton @Startup @PostConstruct not waiting for external client calls

Tags: jakarta-ee, singleton, ejb, postconstruct

I have tested this behaviour in GlassFish 3.1 and Jboss AS 6.1.

In my test, I've configured an application as follows: 
1) a Singleton which has Postconstruct method which takes about 1.5 minutes to end (with thread.sleep()), 
2) a Stateless Bean (named "Abean") with a @Schedule method running every 30 seconds, 
3) a Stateless Bean (named "Bbean") which is called by an external client request just after application deploy (to test scenario depicted in EJB 3.1

specs). 
Notice: Singleton is NEVER injected in any EJB bean.

When I deploy this application in the application Server, I can observe what follows:

Both Jboss and GlassFish servers allow both scheduled calls and external client calls to reach their target Stateless beans "Abean" and "Bbean", while Singleton is still executing its Postconstruct method.

It seems to me that both these Application Servers are not compliant with EJB 3.1 specs as concerns external client calls (see par. 4.8.1 ejb-3_1-fr-specs).
I would like also to know if their behaviour is right as regards scheduled calls (I'm thinking about @Startup pattern...)

Here is my test application code:

Singleton bean

```
package ejbBeans;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.SessionContext;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;

@Startup
@Singleton
public class TestSessionBeanSingleton {


    @Resource
    SessionContext context;

    public TestSessionBeanSingleton() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("TestSessionBeanSingleton Constructor called");      
    }

    @PostConstruct  
    private void init() {       
        System.out.println("TestSessionBeanSingleton postconstruct called " + new Date());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(90000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("TestSessionBeanSingleton postconstruct InterruptedException");
        }
        System.out.println("TestSessionBeanSingleton postconstruct End after 1,5 min "  + new Date());
    }



    public void method1() {
        System.out.println("TestSessionBeanSingleton method1 called");
    }
}
```

Stateless Bean "Abean"

```
package ejbBeans;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.Remote;
import javax.ejb.SessionContext;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;


@Stateless
@Remote(TestInterfaceStateless.class)
public class TestSessionBeanStateless implements TestInterfaceStateless {


    @Resource
    SessionContext context;


    public TestSessionBeanStateless() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("TestSessionBeanStateless Constructor called");      
    }

    @PostConstruct  
    private void init() {
        System.out.println("TestSessionBeanStateless postconstruct called");        
    }

    public void method1(String x, Long y) {
        System.out.println("TestSessionBeanStateless method1 called: String = " + x + " Long = " + y);
    }


}
```

"Abean" Remote Interface

```
package ejbBeans;

public interface TestInterfaceStateless {
    public void method1(String x, Long y);

}
```

Scheduled method bean "Bbean"

```
package ejbBeans;


import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.ejb.Schedule;
import javax.ejb.SessionContext;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
public class TestTimerServiceBean {

    @Resource
    SessionContext sessionContext;

    @Schedule(second="*/30", minute="*",hour="*",persistent=false, info="myScheduled") 
    public void scheduledMethod() {
        System.out.println("TestTimerServiceBean autoScheduledTimedMethod called");
    }

}
```

External Client

```
package ejbClient;

import ejbBeans.TestInterfaceStateless;
import ejbBeans.TestSessionBeanStateless;

public class TestStatelessClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            TestInterfaceStateless sessionBeanEjb  = (TestInterfaceStateless) ServiceLocator.locateServerSessionBean(TestInterfaceStateless.class, TestSessionBeanStateless.class, ServiceLocator.ViewType.REMOTE);             
            sessionBeanEjb.method1("test",25L);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Service Locator for External Client

```
package ejbClient;

import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;


public class ServiceLocator {

    public static enum ViewType {
        NO_INTERFACE("no-interface"),
        LOCAL("local"),
        REMOTE("remote");

        private String name;

        private ViewType(String  name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }


    protected static Object locateServerSessionBean(Class<?> beanIterface, Class<?> beanClassName, ViewType viewType) {     
        Object bean = null;     
        bean = locateJboss(beanIterface, beanClassName, viewType);
        if (bean == null)
            bean = locateGlassfish(beanIterface, beanClassName, viewType);
        return bean;    
    }


    private static Object locateJboss(Class<?> beanIterface, Class<?> beanClassName, ViewType viewType) {
        String jndiLookupString =  beanClassName.getSimpleName();
        switch (viewType)  {
            case NO_INTERFACE:
                    jndiLookupString += "/" + viewType.name; 
                    break;
            case LOCAL:
            case REMOTE:                
                    jndiLookupString += "/" + viewType.name + "-" + beanIterface.getCanonicalName(); 
                    break;                  
        }
        try {           
            Properties env = new Properties();
            env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
            env.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
            env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "jnp://localhost:1099");
            InitialContext context = new InitialContext(env);  
            Object bean = context.lookup(jndiLookupString);
            return bean;            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Locator: bean not found with Jboss name: " +jndiLookupString +", return null");
            return null;
        }       
    }


    private static Object locateGlassfish(Class<?> beanIterface, Class<?> beanClassName, ViewType viewType) {       
        String jndiLookupString =  "java:global/TestStartup/" + beanClassName.getSimpleName() + "!" + beanIterface.getCanonicalName();
        try {
            Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
            env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
            InitialContext context = new InitialContext(env); 
            Object bean = context.lookup(jndiLookupString);
            return bean;            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Locator: bean not found with Glassfish name: " +jndiLookupString +", return null");
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Jboss log

```
20:16:08,207 WARN  [org.jboss.ejb3.TimerServiceContainer] EJBTHREE-2193: using deprecated TimerServiceFactory for restoring timers
20:16:08,556 INFO  [org.jboss.ejb3.session.SessionSpecContainer] Starting jboss.j2ee:jar=TestStartup.jar,name=TestSessionBeanSingleton,service=EJB3
20:16:08,557 WARN  [org.jboss.ejb3.session.SessionSpecContainer] EJBTHREE-2126: container jboss.j2ee:jar=TestStartup.jar,name=TestSessionBeanSingleton,service=EJB3 does not verify the businessObjectFactory
20:16:08,557 INFO  [org.jboss.ejb3.EJBContainer] STARTED EJB: ejbBeans.TestSessionBeanSingleton ejbName: TestSessionBeanSingleton
20:16:08,557 WARN  [org.jboss.ejb3.TimerServiceContainer] EJBTHREE-2193: using deprecated TimerServiceFactory for restoring timers
20:16:08,559 INFORMAZIONI [STDOUT] TestSessionBeanSingleton Constructor called
20:16:08,739 INFORMAZIONI [STDOUT] TestSessionBeanSingleton postconstruct called Sat Jan 28 20:16:08 CET 2017
20:16:30,055 INFORMAZIONI [STDOUT] TestTimerServiceBean autoScheduledTimedMethod called
20:16:55,733 INFORMAZIONI [STDOUT] TestSessionBeanStateless Constructor called
20:16:55,735 INFORMAZIONI [STDOUT] TestSessionBeanStateless postconstruct called
20:16:55,761 INFORMAZIONI [STDOUT] TestSessionBeanStateless method1 called: String = test Long = 25
20:17:00,006 INFORMAZIONI [STDOUT] TestTimerServiceBean autoScheduledTimedMethod called
20:17:30,023 INFORMAZIONI [STDOUT] TestTimerServiceBean autoScheduledTimedMethod called
20:17:38,740 INFORMAZIONI [STDOUT] TestSessionBeanSingleton postconstruct End after 1,5 min Sat Jan 28 20:17:38 CET 2017
20:17:38,761 INFORMAZIONI [STDOUT] TestSessionBeanSingleton Constructor called
20:17:38,761 INFO  [org.jboss.ejb3.nointerface.impl.jndi.AbstractNoInterfaceViewBinder] Binding the following entry in Global JNDI for bean:TestSessionBeanSingleton

    TestSessionBeanSingleton/no-interface -> EJB3.1 no-interface view

20:17:38,764 INFO  [org.jboss.ejb3.nointerface.impl.jndi.AbstractNoInterfaceViewBinder] Binding the following entry in Global JNDI for bean:TestTimerServiceBean

    TestTimerServiceBean/no-interface -> EJB3.1 no-interface view

20:18:00,004 INFORMAZIONI [STDOUT] TestTimerServiceBean autoScheduledTimedMethod called
20:18:30,003 INFORMAZIONI [STDOUT] TestTimerServiceBean autoScheduledTimedMethod called
20:19:00,002 INFORMAZIONI [STDOUT] TestTimerServiceBean autoScheduledTimedMethod called
```

GlassFish log

```
2017-01-28T22:11:03.025+0100|Informazioni: JTS5014: Recoverable JTS instance, serverId = [3700]
2017-01-28T22:11:03.900+0100|Informazioni: EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB TestSessionBeanStateless: [java:global/TestStartup/TestSessionBeanStateless!ejbBeans.TestInterfaceStateless, java:global/TestStartup/TestSessionBeanStateless]
2017-01-28T22:11:03.900+0100|Informazioni: EJB5182:Glassfish-specific (Non-portable) JNDI names for EJB TestSessionBeanStateless: [ejbBeans.TestInterfaceStateless#ejbBeans.TestInterfaceStateless, ejbBeans.TestInterfaceStateless]
2017-01-28T22:11:03.985+0100|Informazioni: Loading EJBTimerService. Please wait.
2017-01-28T22:11:04.458+0100|Informazioni: WEB0169: Created HTTP listener [http-listener-1] on host/port [0.0.0.0:8080]
2017-01-28T22:11:04.469+0100|Informazioni: WEB0169: Created HTTP listener [http-listener-2] on host/port [0.0.0.0:8181]
2017-01-28T22:11:04.474+0100|Informazioni: WEB0169: Created HTTP listener [admin-listener] on host/port [0.0.0.0:4848]
2017-01-28T22:11:04.523+0100|Informazioni: WEB0171: Created virtual server [server]
2017-01-28T22:11:04.525+0100|Informazioni: WEB0171: Created virtual server [__asadmin]
2017-01-28T22:11:05.020+0100|Informazioni: WEB0172: Virtual server [server] loaded default web module []
2017-01-28T22:11:09.059+0100|Informazioni: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 4.3.0.Final
2017-01-28T22:11:11.256+0100|Informazioni: EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461
2017-01-28T22:11:13.065+0100|Informazioni: file:/C:/Servers/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/ejb-timer-service-app/WEB-INF/classes/___EJB__Timer__App login successful
2017-01-28T22:11:13.066+0100|Avvertenza: Multiple [2] JMX MBeanServer instances exist, we will use the server at index [0] : [com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.DynamicInterceptor@11d6ecc3].
2017-01-28T22:11:13.066+0100|Avvertenza: JMX MBeanServer in use: [com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.DynamicInterceptor@11d6ecc3] from index [0] 
2017-01-28T22:11:13.066+0100|Avvertenza: JMX MBeanServer in use: [com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer@44c3b4dd] from index [1] 
2017-01-28T22:11:13.133+0100|Informazioni: [TimerBeanContainer] Created  TimerBeanContainer: TimerBean
2017-01-28T22:11:13.163+0100|Informazioni: EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB TimerBean: [java:global/ejb-timer-service-app/TimerBean, java:global/ejb-timer-service-app/TimerBean!com.sun.ejb.containers.TimerLocal]
2017-01-28T22:11:13.367+0100|Informazioni: WEB0671: Loading application [ejb-timer-service-app] at [/ejb-timer-service-app]
2017-01-28T22:11:13.369+0100|Informazioni: EJB5109:EJB Timer Service started successfully for data source [jdbc/__TimerPool]
2017-01-28T22:11:13.372+0100|Informazioni: Setting DBReadBeforeTimeout to false
2017-01-28T22:11:13.372+0100|Informazioni: ==> Restoring Timers ... 
2017-01-28T22:11:13.805+0100|Informazioni: There are no EJB Timers owned by this server
2017-01-28T22:11:13.805+0100|Informazioni: <== ... Timers Restored.
2017-01-28T22:11:13.809+0100|Informazioni: EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB TestTimerServiceBean: [java:global/TestStartup/TestTimerServiceBean, java:global/TestStartup/TestTimerServiceBean!ejbBeans.TestTimerServiceBean]
2017-01-28T22:11:13.836+0100|Informazioni: EJB5181:Portable JNDI names for EJB TestSessionBeanSingleton: [java:global/TestStartup/TestSessionBeanSingleton!ejbBeans.TestSessionBeanSingleton, java:global/TestStartup/TestSessionBeanSingleton]
2017-01-28T22:11:13.840+0100|Informazioni: TestSessionBeanSingleton Constructor called
2017-01-28T22:11:13.869+0100|Informazioni: TestSessionBeanSingleton Constructor called
2017-01-28T22:11:13.873+0100|Informazioni: TestSessionBeanSingleton postconstruct called Sat Jan 28 22:11:13 CET 2017
2017-01-28T22:11:30.015+0100|Informazioni: TestTimerServiceBean autoScheduledTimedMethod called
2017-01-28T22:11:44.763+0100|Informazioni: TestSessionBeanStateless Constructor called
2017-01-28T22:11:44.765+0100|Informazioni: TestSessionBeanStateless postconstruct called
2017-01-28T22:11:44.766+0100|Informazioni: TestSessionBeanStateless method1 called: String = test Long = 25
2017-01-28T22:12:00.002+0100|Informazioni: TestTimerServiceBean autoScheduledTimedMethod called
2017-01-28T22:12:30.002+0100|Informazioni: TestTimerServiceBean autoScheduledTimedMethod called
2017-01-28T22:12:43.873+0100|Informazioni: TestSessionBeanSingleton postconstruct End after 1,5 min Sat Jan 28 22:12:43 CET 2017
2017-01-28T22:12:43.878+0100|Informazioni: CORE10010: Loading application TestStartup done in 109.016 ms
2017-01-28T22:12:43.882+0100|Informazioni: Oracle GlassFish Server 3.1.2.2 (5) startup time : Felix (3.797ms), startup services(110.692ms), total(114.489ms)
2017-01-28T22:12:47.603+0100|Informazioni: JMX005: JMXStartupService had Started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://192.168.1.7:8686/jndi/rmi://192.168.1.7:8686/jmxrmi
2017-01-28T22:13:00.002+0100|Informazioni: TestTimerServiceBean autoScheduledTimedMethod called
```

Comment: Do you have a small amount of code to show the issue?  I've not run into this but I may be doing things differently.

Comment: newInstance()? My two cents on this, use '@Startup' for '@Singleton'

Comment: I must apologize, I've better checked Jboss behaviour, I missed Jboss Singleton PostConstruct method call, soon after instance constructor call. Really both Jboss and GlassFish run the same way.